# Converting javascript element to html while keeping the associated events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have created a checkbox directly in javascript, and binded a click event the following way :

```
let checkBox = document.createElement('input');
checkBox.onclick = (e) => {
  console.log("click", e);
};
```

Now I would like to convert this element to plain html, while keeping the associated event. I now I can call checkBox.outerHTML to get the associated html, but the event would disappear.

Is there a way to do the same thing without removing the attached event ?

Comment: _"plain html"_ is a string. How is a string supposed to have events?

Comment: The callback associated to the event could be explicit in the string

Comment: @AlexisPister — not in the general case, since the scope rules would be different.

Comment: Well, the general case wouldn't matter if it doesn't need to be an auto generator. Is this the case?

Comment: You could give the checkbox an ID or class and attach the event listener to it in JS  - perhaps delegate from its container

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you need such an approach when you simply can append that element where ever you want. Yet, it is still simple to just fix it the way it is.
Instead of assigning an event, you should assign an attribute like this:

```js
const checkBox = document.createElement('input');
checkBox.setAttribute("onclick", "cbxClicked(event)");

function cbxClicked(e) {
  console.log("click", e);
};

console.log(checkBox.outerHTML); // <input onclick="cbxClicked(event)">
```

Tested well on chrome.

Comment: Eeuuw. Why not `checkBox.addEventListener("click",cbxClicked)`

Comment: He needs the event to remain after the element is converted to plain HTML @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is this

```
window.addEventListner("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("checkboxContainer")
    .addEventListener("click",function(e) { 
    const tgt = e.target; 
    if (tgt.type && tgt.type==="checkbox") {
      console.log("click",tgt) 
    }
  });
});
```

Now you can create your checkboxes before or after load

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const container = document.getElementById("checkboxContainer");
  container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "checkbox") {
      console.log("click", tgt)
    }
  });
  const inp = document.createElement("input")
  inp.type = "checkbox";
  inp.value = "dynamic";
  container.appendChild(inp);
});
```

```html
<div id="checkboxContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" value="static" />
</div>
```